# how to add multiple ethernet interfaces to linux

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

To add a new ethernet interface I entered this command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 172.20.0.56 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

following error comes:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
```

Whereas  the command works with `eth0`

Do I need to add a driver for new mac? Where would I add this driver? Do I need to change something in the bootloader?

Or is there some other solution?

When I connect a WiFi dongle to computer then automatically a new interface `eth1` comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you do ifconfig -a it will show you all devices recognized by the system. If eth1 is not present there, system does not see it. Do you have two Ethernet cards ?